# How to split required text from SQL Server table columns

Tags: sql-server, csv

I used a query which splits the texts in a column in one table and retrieves the corresponding id's from another table.

Here is the query:

```
DECLARE @X XML
DECLARE @STR VARCHAR(MAX) = ''

SELECT @STR = @STR + ';' + P_AUTHOR
FROM sub_aminer_paper
WHERE PID = 4
ORDER BY PID

SELECT @STR = substring(@STR,2,len(@STR))

SELECT @X = CONVERT(xml,' <root> <s>' + REPLACE(@STR,';','</s> <s>') + '</s>   </root> ')

SELECT aid as [Author_id], name as [Author_Name]
FROM sub_aminer_author s
INNER JOIN 
    (SELECT 
         row_number() OVER(ORDER BY (SELECT null)) AS rn,  
         T.c.value('.','varchar(max)') AS value
     FROM 
         @X.nodes('/root/s') T(c) ) t ON t.value = s.name
ORDER BY rn
```

If column `p_author` contains this value i.e.

```
Sushil Jajodia;Peter A. Ng;Frederick N. Springsteel
```

Then this query gives following output i.e.

```
Author_id   Author_Name
 578328     Sushil Jajodia
 865779     Peter A. Ng
 669143     Frederick N. Springsteel
```

Now I want to have `Author_id` as skipping first author id e.g. I need output like this:

```
Author_id   Author_Name
 865779     Peter A. Ng
 669143     Frederick N. Springsteel
```

Then also I have to insert these `Author_id`'s in another table. Please help regarding this query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add `WHERE rn>1`

```
DECLARE @X XML
DECLARE @STR VARCHAR(MAX)=''
        SELECT @STR = @STR+';'+P_AUTHOR
        FROM sub_aminer_paper
        WHERE PID = 4
        ORDER BY PID

        SELECT @STR = substring(@STR,2,len(@STR))

        SELECT @X = CONVERT(xml,' <root> <s>' + REPLACE(@STR,';','</s> <s>') + '</s>   </root> ')

        SELECT aid as [Author_id], name as [Author_Name]
        FROM sub_aminer_author s
        INNER JOIN (SELECT row_number() 
                    OVER(ORDER BY (SELECT null)) AS rn, T.c.value('.','varchar(max)') AS value
                    FROM @X.nodes('/root/s') T(c)
                   ) t ON t.value = s.name
         WHERE rn>1
                    ORDER BY rn
```

Comment: @DarkKnight--Can we select aid for greater number of PID's as here in this query there is only single PID i.e. PID=4???

Comment: @user5313087 : yes, you can. Just remove PID from where.

Comment: @DarkKnight--query taking too long to respond, actually I mean to say I have a set of PID's i.e. round about 2000 PID's for which I have to split author ID's